In Prisma, using Typed Sql, is there a way to define arguments as nullable?
For example, in this basic pagination query, cursor should be nullable, but I can't find it in the docs or find a way that works.
-- @param {String} $1:cursor
-- @param {Int} $2:limit
SELECT
    l.id,
    n.notebooks
FROM
    location l
    JOIN get_location_notebooks() n ON l.id = n.location_id
WHERE ($1 IS NULL OR id > $1::UUID)
LIMIT COALESCE($2::INT, 10);

